# How to create and assign a group to an fcurve with python script?

Tags: python, fcurves

I am attempting to make an addon/script with blender python that works with mocap files (.bvh), my problem is that when the files are imported the group collection on [fcurve.group](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/bpy.types.FCurve.html#bpy.types.FCurve.group) is blank

```
for fcurve in bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action.fcurves:
        if fcurve.group is not None:
            print(text='Source object fcurve group ' + fcurve.group.name)
```

**How do I create and assign a group to the fcurve with python script?**

```
fcurve.group = bpy.types.FCurve.new("LocRot") #what i tried first
```

**Explanation of why:**
When i import the files they have rotation mode XZY Euler on all the bones, I am attempting to use [this](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?388197-Quat-Euler-Rotation-Mode-Converter) script to convert the rotation mode to Quaternion however it fails due to the fact that the bones have no groups on them.... (hence my question)

Ultimately I plan to make my own pipeline which handles the small problems I have with the .bvh files when imported, such as converting FK -> IK

My full code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/whdSfxDf) and [here](https://pastebin.com/jg2hvkFE) if that helps at all

[image: UI so far]

Comment: Why is this a problem? What do you do with the BVH files that Blender's importer doesn't do already?

Comment: dr Sybren: all i am trying to do is assign a new group to an fcurve, do you know how to do it?
`fcurve.group = bpy.types.FCurve.new("LocRot")` looked promising however i don't think i used it right cause it didn't work [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/bpy.types.ActionGroups.html#bpy.types.ActionGroups.new)

Answer (score 4):

Both the [fcurves](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FCurve.html) themselves, and the [action groups](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ActionGroup.html) are part of the [action](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Action.html) object. You have to create new groups through the action and then assign that group to any fcurves you want inside it.

```
armature = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
anim_data = armature.animation_data
action = anim_data.action

# create a new group
group_1 = action.groups.new("group_1")

# assign the first three fcurves to the new group
for fcurve in anim_data.action.fcurves[:3]:
    fcurve.group = group
```